# Kotlin Spring Boot form-urlencoded POST requests with a Map

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I've just started playing around with Kotlin and Spring Boot and decided to write a simple endpoint that takes a form-urlencoded POST request. I didn't feel like writing an actual data class for the body, so I tried to just use a Map for the body, hoping I could just access key/value pairs. I first tried:

```
@RestController
class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST),
            consumes = arrayOf("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
    fun myEndpoint(@RequestBody body: Map<String,String>): String {

        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

But that resulted in a 415 error about unsupported media type...which I read was due to the use of @RequestBody and form-urlencoded POSTs. I subsequently tried using the @ModelAttribute instead but then received

> Failed to instantiate [java.util.Map]: Specified class is an interface

Hardly surprising as I was completely hacking. I also tried without any annotations for the body, but then none of the form parameters were injected. I know I could add a data class to solve this, but I'd like to know if this can be done generically using a Map as I've done a similar thing in Java before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to annotate your `body` param with `@RequestParam`

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = [(RequestMethod.POST)],
                    consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE])
    fun myEndpoint(@RequestParam body: Map<String,String>): String {

        return //...
    }
```

(Also note that I removed the `arrayOf` calls in favour of array literals, which are available for annotations as of Kotlin 1.2)